# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre commit y push en GIT?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

Recientemente cambiamos de SVN a GIT en el proyecto, con `git commit` se guardan los cambios que se han hecho localmente. Entonces, ¿para qué sirve `git push`?¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los comandos `git push` y `git commit`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git push` es un comando que sube los cambios hechos en tu ambiente de trabajo a una rama de trabajo tuya y/o de tu equipo remota. Commit identifica los cambios hechos en dicho ambiente de trabajo. Si tu no haces un `push` de tus cambios, estos jamás se verán reflejados en tu repositorio remoto.

A nivel de trabajo `git push` trabaja a nivel de repositorio, es decir con tu repositorio remoto, mientras que `git commit` trabaja en tu repositorio local.

**EDIT**

Cuando ocupas el comando `git status` y anteriormente hiciste un commit sin haber hecho `git push` (sin haber aplicado los cambios en tu repositorio remoto) puedes verificar los archivos que localmente modificaste. A esto me referia que "identifica" un commit.

Comment: Buena explicación y bien resumida, para mí la más completa aunque donde pones "Commit identifica" supongo que te referirás a que los guarda en el repositorio local.

Comment: claro, a lo que me referia como "identifica" es que los guarda en el repositorio local, de hecho editare mi respuesta para explicar algo que seme fue

Comment: Si, yo lo entendí pero igual podía confundir de alguna manera al OP. Buena respuesta de todas formas ;)

Comment: Gracias! @Error404 saludos!

Answer (score 6):

Para complementar las posibles respuestas, hago cita a una imagen en una pregunta en el [StackOverFlow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745076/what-are-the-differences-between-git-commit-and-git-push).

En términos muy básicos push manda los cambios a tu repositorio remoto, mientras commit lo hace al repositorio local.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`git push` sube los cambios al repositorio central, comúnmente llamado origin, para que otros desarrolladores puedan bajarse tus cambios.